# Second scope after struct definition

Tags: c++11, syntax

I looked a bit into Eric Nieblers range library https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/ and there (/include/range/v3/utility/concepts.hpp, line 36) I found code of the form

```
constexpr struct valid_expr_t
{
    template<typename ...T>
    true_ operator()(T &&...) const;
} valid_expr {};
```

I am confused to the second scope/braces after valid_expr. What is the meaning of the whole construct. Is this even a struct definition? The syntax seems not allowed in C++98. What can go into these second pair of braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the C++11 [uniform initialization syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization), and it simply initializes the `valid_expr` object.

It's like doing

```
struct valid_expr_t
{
    template<typename ...T>
    true_ operator()(T &&...) const;
};

constexpr valid_expr_t valid_expr {};
```